# How can I create a boundary using C# code only?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a unity script that detects when the player has left a certain area using C# code only (no boundary boxes). My code should play a sound once the player leaves but the code is not working as expected and I cannot see a fault in the logic.

**Expected behaviour**

When the player steps outside the boundary, a sound will play once.

**Actual Behaviour**

The sound plays all the time no matter where the player is.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EX2BoundaryDetect : MonoBehaviour {

    // create a GameObject to represent the player
    public GameObject playerObject;
    public bool leaveArea = false;

    // create an Audio-clip object. This assumes we drag a sound file onto the myclip box in the Inspector.
    public AudioClip myclip;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        // associate playerObject with the player. This assumes the First Person Controller is name "player
        playerObject = GameObject.Find ("player");

        // get the actual Sound file from the Inspector
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip = myclip;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        PlayAudio1();
        if (leaveArea) {
            GetComponent<AudioSource> ().Play ();
        }
    }

    public void PlayAudio1 () {

        // play the sound if the player is outside some boundaries

        if (transform.position.x > 10) {
            leaveArea = true;
        }

        if (transform.position.x < -29) {
            leaveArea = true;
        }

        if (transform.position.z > 10) {
            leaveArea = true;
        }

        if (transform.position.z < -29) {
            leaveArea = true;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `if (leaveArea = true)` possible unintended assignment of variable in expression.

Comment: @DeanOC OP didn't roll the solution into the question. The 2nd revision also did not work.

Comment: @Ruzihm Thanks for pointing that out. I hadn't realised that the OP's answer had 1 line different to the edited question. I've restored the rolled back code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working now, by adding

```
leaveArea = false;
```

to the `Update` method.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EX2BoundaryDetect : MonoBehaviour {

    // create a GameObject to represent the player
    public GameObject playerObject;
    public bool leaveArea = false;

    // create an Audio-clip object. This assumes we drag a sound file onto the myclip box in the Inspector.
    public AudioClip myclip;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        // associate playerObject with the player. This assumes the First Person Controller is name "player
        playerObject = GameObject.Find ("player");

        // get the actual Sound file from the Inspector
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip = myclip;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        PlayAudio1();
        if (leaveArea) {
            GetComponent<AudioSource> ().Play ();
        }

        leaveArea = false;
    }

    public void PlayAudio1 () {

        // play the sound if the player is outside some boundaries

        if (transform.position.x > 10) {
            leaveArea = true;
        }

        if (transform.position.x < -29) {
            leaveArea = true;
        }

        if (transform.position.z > 10) {
            leaveArea = true;
        }

        if (transform.position.z < -29) {
            leaveArea = true;
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

`leaveArea` is only set to `false` in the class definition. Once set to `true`, it may never be set to `false` again, and it may be inadvertently overwritten in the scene definition in the first place.

To fix this issue, set it to `false` at the beginning of `Update`:

```
void Update () {

    leaveArea = false;
    PlayAudio1();
    if (leaveArea) {
        GetComponent<AudioSource> ().Play ();
    }
}
```

Also, `GetComponent` is an expensive action and it is good to avoid calling it in `Update` wherever possible. Therefore, you may want to move it into a class property and set it once in `Start`:

```
private AudioSource audioSource;

void Start () {

    // associate playerObject with the player. This assumes the First Person Controller is name "player
    playerObject = GameObject.Find ("player");

    audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

    // get the actual Sound file from the Inspector
    audioSource.clip = myclip;

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    leaveArea = false;
    PlayAudio1();
    if (leaveArea) {
        audioSource.Play ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the above answers still do not solve your problem of **"When the player steps outside the boundary, a sound will play once."**

I will share a cleaner way of doing it (possibly optimized)

**Using Bounds**

Create our own bounds by using `Bounds` https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.html

The constructor of `Bounds` is `Bounds(Vector3 center,vector3 size)`

So in your case center will be `center = (-9.5f, 0, -9.5f)` (midpoint formula) and finally the size of the bounding box will be `size = (39.0f, 0f, 39.0f)`

Let's move to the Code Part

```
public class BoundsCheck: MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isInside = false;
    public bool isPlayedOnce = false;
    private Bounds bounds;

    void Start()
    {
        bounds = new Bounds(new Vector3(-9.5f, 0, -9.5f), new Vector3(39.0f, 0f, 39.0f));
    }


    void Update()
    {
        CheckBounds();// play the sound if the player is outside some boundaries
        if (!isInside &&!isPlayedOnce)
        {
            Debug.Log("PLAY");
            isPlayedOnce = true;
        }
    }

    private void CheckBounds()
    {


        bool isInsideBound = bounds.Contains(transform.position);
        if (isInsideBound)
        {
            isInside = true;
            if (isPlayedOnce)
            {
                isPlayedOnce = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            isInside = false;
        }
    }
}
```

So instead of multiple ifs, we can just check if the position of the transform is inside the bound by using `bool isInsideBound = bounds.Contains(transform.position);`

Note:- **To play sound only once, I have used one more boolean `isPlayedOnce`**

I am not sure if this the most optimized way of doing it. But surely a cleaner way(via code).